# CURL request is not capturing data in Flask app when passed request using POST

Tags: python, curl, flask, request

I am a novice in Flask framework. I have made an app which is suppose to provide some NLP-NER results. The app works fine with when I CURL using GET, but while doing this I have to encode the URL which is taking some time. I want to use POST and send the data to the app. I have tried various ways mentioned but unable to find a solution. This is what I am sending using cURL.

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:5000/ner -d "text=I am avinash"
```

Error: No text field provided. Please specify text to process.(base) Avinashs-MBP:NER avinash.chourasiya$

This is my flask app:

```
import spacy, sys, json
from spacy import displacy
import flask
from flask import request

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route('/',methods=['POST'])
def home():
    return "<h1>Spacy NLP Demo</h1><p>This site is a prototype API for Spacy NLP</p>"

@app.route('/ner', methods=['POST'])
def ner():
    print(request.args,"The post is working, but it is not reading the requests")
    if 'text' in request.args:
         text = request.args['text']
    else:
         return "Error: No text field provided. Please specify text to process."

    #Limit the text size to 10K characters for safety
    print("text len: ", len(text))
    text = request.args['text']
    truncated_text = text[:10000]
    doc = nlp(truncated_text)

    ents = []
    for sent in doc.sents:
        for span in sent.ents:
            ent = {"verbatim": span.text, "ent_type": span.label_, "hit_span_start": span.start_char, "hit_span_end": span.end_char }
            ents.append(ent)


    return json.dumps(ents)
 app.run()
```

This app works fine with the GET. Please help me out in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know that the data will be sent from `curl` as a **urlencoded form**. So, to get the data from that POST request, you have to use `request.form` not `request.args`

So, the `ner()` method should be like so:

```
@app.route('/ner', methods=['POST'])
def ner():
    print(request.form,"The post is working, but it is not reading the requests")
    if 'text' in request.form:
        text = request.form['text']
    else:
        return "Error: No text field provided. Please specify text to process."

    #Limit the text size to 10K characters for safety
    print("text len: ", len(text))
    text = request.form['text']
    ...
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a `post` and expecting data in `get` format.

You need to get data from `form`.

```
    text = request.form.get("text")
    if not text:
        return "Error: No text field provided. Please specify text to process."
```

Similarly everywhere.